# Comparison of two alternating series- Which is bigger

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Imagine you have two finite alternating series.

$$S_a=a_1-a_2+a_3-a_4+\cdots+a_n$$

$$S_b=b_1-b_2+b_3-b_4+\cdots+ b_n$$

**Question:**
If $|a_i|>|b_i|$ is $S_a>S_b$?

Comment: No. Choose $a_1 = 2, a_2 = 1, a_3, ..., a_n = \frac 1 2$, together with $b_1 = 1, b_2, ..., b_n = 0$. When $n$ has the right parity, $S_a = S_b$.

Comment: What is the relation between $a_i$ and $b_i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$S_a=a_1-a_2+a_3-a_4+\cdots+a_n$$

$$S_b=b_1-b_2+b_3-b_4+\cdots+ b_n$$

$$S_b-S_a=\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor} b_{2i-1}-a_{2i-1} + \sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor} a_{2i}-b_{2i} $$

From that one clearly one can make the difference in the odd members small and in the even members great or visceversa to obtain any sign.

Answer (score 1):

No, suppose all $a_i$ are equal and set to a large positive number $N$, and $n$ is even. Then $S_a = 0$. Certainly you can define an alternating sequence of  numbers with absolute value less than $N$ such that the sum $S_b$ is positive.

Answer (score 0):

No, say $a_1 = 1$, $b_1 = 0$, $a_2 = 10$, $b_2 = 1$, then
$$
a_1 - a_2 = 1-10 = -9
$$
and
$$
b_1 - b_2 = 0-1 = -1
$$

Comment: Also each $a_i$ and $b_i$ is positive

Comment: Changed it. Same conclusion.